# Is this custom malloc OK?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, pointer-arithmetic

I need to write a custom malloc for GPU programming. Will this work correctly?

```
void* malloc(int size, int* bytesUsed, uchar* memory){
  int startIdx = (*bytesUsed);
  (*bytesUsed) += size;
  return (void*)(memory+startIdx);
}
```

I'm new to C programming, I might have made pointer-arithmetic related errors or something... the idea is `bytesUsed` gives you the index into `memory` of the first free address, so you increment it by `size` and then return the incremented index as a pointer.

Comment: If you're on POSIX check out http://linux.die.net/man/2/sbrk

Comment: What happens when you need to `free`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I don't need to free; when the workgroup finishes all memory is seized and reused for the next workgroup. (I'm using openCL).

Comment: If you are new to C why try to run before you are able to walk? Answer to the question is no

Comment: @stackptr I'm on the GPU using openCL :(.

Comment: @EdHeal Because I need to port some computations to the GPU... I'm using pyopencl and doing all the host stuff in python, but there's a certain amount of unavoidable C stuff. And I need malloc because I'm building a tree node by node in shared (local in openCL-speak) memory.

Comment: @EdHeal I would also appreciate an explanation of how I can fix it...

Comment: @RenéG I suppose you might find [this](https://forums.khronos.org/showthread.php/7441-Memory-allocation-inside-kernel) conversation on `malloc` in OpenCL usefull

Comment: @EliKorvigo Yes, I saw that; the solution they propose is to pass a pointer to a large array and manually manage memory inside. Which is what I'm trying to do.

Comment: For a start - is free possible? Is running out of memory catered for?

Comment: @EdHeal I don't need free and I don't need to worry about running out: this is for a very specific one-time use. I only need unsafe malloc without free (by unsafe I mean I'm fine with segfaults if I go over since I know I'm not going to go over). What I'm asking is, is what I wrote good enough for that?

Comment: Famous last words "don't need to worry". Fatal flaw not checking if there is enough memory and returning `NULL`. After that use `unsigned` types, then the size limit will catch accidental negatives.

Comment: Should be `return memory+startIdx;`

Comment: Order independent transparency deals with dynamic allocation in shaders, perhaps you could borrow their technique.

Comment: @user3386109 Good catch! You're completely right. I will fix that. Thanks for actually looking at the code instead of just being pedantic about stuff that doesn't matter for what I'm doing.

Comment: Writing unsafe code is a very bad habit to get into

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Edit 2023] `sizeof(max_align_t)` corrected to `alignof(max_align_t)`.

There are some issues:

1. Largest problem is alignment.   The returned pointer needs to be aligned.  Since this `malloc()` is not given the pointer type needed, use `max_align_t`  "which is an object type whose alignment is as great as is supported by the implementation in all contexts" C11dr §7.19 2.  Note:  `*bytesUsed` needs this alignment too.  So apply similar code should if other code affects it.

   ```
    if (size%alignof(max_align_t)) {
      size += alignof(max_align_t) - size%alignof(max_align_t);
    }
    // or
    size = (size + alignof(max_align_t) - 1)/alignof(max_align_t)*alignof(max_align_t);
   ```
2. No detection for out-of-memory.
3. Avoid re-using standard library names.  Code can `define` them in later, if needed.

   ```
    // void* malloc(int size, int* bytesUsed, uchar* memory);
    void* RG_malloc(int size, int* bytesUsed, uchar* memory);

    // if needed
    #define malloc RF_malloc
   ```
4. `malloc()` expects a different type for allocations: `size_t`, not `int`.

   ```
    // void* malloc(int size, int* bytesUsed, uchar* memory);
    void* malloc(size_t size, size_t* bytesUsed, uchar* memory);
   ```
5. Cast is not needed.

   ```
    // return (void*)(memory+startIdx);
    return memory + startIdx;
   ```
6. More clear to use `unsigned char` than `uchar`, which hopefully is not something else.

Putting this all together

```
void* malloc(size_t size, size_t* bytesUsed, unsigned char* memory){
  size = (size + alignof(max_align_t) - 1)/alignof(max_align_t)*alignof(max_align_t);
  if (RG_ALLOC_SIZE - *bytesUsed > size) {
    return NULL;
  }
  size_t startIdx = *bytesUsed;  // See note above concerning alignment.
  *bytesUsed += size;
  return memory + startIdx;
}
```

Additionally, `RG_free()` is not coded.  If that is needed, this simply allocation scheme would need significant additions.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this simple stack-based solution will work for you

```
#include <stdint.h>
const size_t ALLOCSIZE = 1024;
typedef uint8_t byte;

static byte buf[ALLOCSIZE];
static byte *pbuf = buf;

byte *alloc(size_t n)
{
    /* if there is room */
    if (buf + ALLOCSIZE - pbuf >= n) {
        pbuf += n;
        return pbuf - n;
    } else
        return NULL;
}
```

I didn't provide a `free`, since you said you didn't need to deallocate.